# Spring Boot Jpa custom Id generator with composite key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore

In a spring boot application entity I have a unique field A and unique field B.  I would like to create a id generator that generates an Integer id that is unique across column A and column B.  What is the easiest way to achieve this? Our repository will be extending DatastoreRepository.  I would like for the generated Id be a concatenation:

int generatedId= "column A + column B + <6 digit generated value>"

Answer (score 1):

A [custom generator](https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/) might work for you. Inside the `generate` method, you'll be able to both access the entity (via the `object` parameter) as well as call the `super` implementation for a DB sequence-generated value.

You can also make your generator implement the more generic `IdGenerator` (instead of inheriting from `SequenceStyleGenerator`) if you want to handle sequence number generation some other way. The `session` parameter will basically allow you to execute arbitrary SQL against the DB.